# how can I show parameters that get from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to do like twitter/instagram profile url address and I want to get data from database. like: example.com/{username}. But I can not do that because I'm beginner in Laravel. How can I do this? And I'm using Laravel 8 and are my last two routes correct?

**My web.php is:**

```
Route::get('/test', [HomeController::class, 'test'])->name('test');

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/profile', function () {
    return view('design2.profile');
})->name('profile');
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/settings', function () {
    return view('design2.settings');
})->name('settings');
```

**My HomeController is:**

```
public function test(){
    return view('design2.test');
}

public function settings(){
    return view('design2.settings');
}

public function profile(){
    return view('design2.profile');
}
```

Comment: If you know that you can not do it, why are you ask "How can you do it" ? actually you just need to read the routing documentation, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#required-parameters

Answer (score 0):

This documentation link that is going to help you: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters

But here is a simple example

```
Route::get('/{username}', function ($username) {
     // Logic to show the data
});
```

Comment: but i want to get data from database, i have a database

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this, but the simplest way would look something like this:

```php
Route::get('profile/{username}', [HomeController::class, 'profile']);
```

And then use the `$username` parameter from your controller like so:

```php
public function profile($username){
    // The following line assumes you have a model called "User"
    //    and a property / DB column called "username" that you're wanting in the URL.
    //    firstOrFail will return a 404 error automatically if the username isn't found
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->firstOrFail();
 
    return view('design2.profile', compact('user'));
}
```

Then in your `design2.profile` blade file `$user` can be used like so:

```html
<h1>{{ $user->fullName}}'s Profile</h1>
<ul>
  <li>First Name: {{ $user->firstName }}</li>
  <li>Last Name: {{ $user->lastName}}</li>
  <li>Email: {{ $user->email }}</li>
</ul>
```